# C# Stack<T> source code unboxing to object question

Tags: c#, generics, stack

my question is: why is the unboxing to Object necessary for comparing to null for both item and _array[count]? thanks.
source code here:
https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs#L119

```
public bool Contains(T item) {
        int count = _size;

        EqualityComparer<T> c = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
        while (count-- > 0) {
            if (((Object) item) == null) {
                if (((Object) _array[count]) == null)
                    return true;
            }
            else if (_array[count] != null && c.Equals(_array[count], item) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: In what way is that unboxing? It's potentially a *boxing* operation when `T` is a value type... it's never an unboxing operation. It's not actually required in the source code, but I suppose putting the cast in the code makes it clearer that it *is* a boxing operation. (I'm not sure why `item` is being boxed on each iteration though.) I wouldn't treat the reference source as production code, mind you... see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/Stack.cs#L80 for the code in the actual runtime these days.

Comment: You're right, it's a boxing operation, thanks for your input!